# MeteorJS -- Internal server error [500] -- No Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I implemented a fully scaffolded Meteor project, and removed 'autopublish', and when I try to call even this simple function:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'test'(){
        alert('test called');
    },
});
```

I get the error:

```
Error invoking Method 'test': Internal server error [500]
```

I try calling another Method which doesn't even call an error, which is why I stripped down the function to the bare minimum.

All other solutions I look for talk about subscribing to databases, except I've taken all that information out -- what could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should throw an error, because `Meteor.methods` is run in server and `alert` is not defined in server side. `alert` is available in client side only. If you look at the server log you will find this:  `Exception while invoking method 'a' ReferenceError: alert is not defined`.

If you are trying to print something in server side use `console.log` instead. In your case;

```
Meteor.methods({
    'test'(){
        console.log('test called');
    },
});
```